# Dataframe left outer join not working correctly in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have two dataframe with below schema:

```
clusterDF schema
root
 |-- cluster_id: string (nullable = true)

df schema
root
 |-- cluster_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Trying to join these using

```
val nameDF  = clusterDF.join(df, col("clusterDF.cluster_id") === col("df.cluster_id"), "left" )
```

But above code fails with:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`clusterDF.cluster_id`' given input columns: [cluster_id, cluster_id, name];;
'Join LeftOuter, ('clusterDF.cluster_id = 'df.cluster_id)
:- Aggregate [cluster_id#0], [cluster_id#0]
:  +- Project [cluster_id#0]
:     +- Filter (name#18 = kroger)
:        +- Project [cluster_id#0, name#18]
:           +- Generate explode(influencers#1.screenName), true, false, [name#18]
:              +- Relation[cluster_id#0,influencers#1] json
+- Project [cluster_id#26, name#18]
   +- Generate explode(influencers#27.screenName), true, false, [name#18]
      +- Relation[cluster_id#26,influencers#27] json
```

Seems very weird to me. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is clear enough

> > org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`clusterDF.cluster_id`' given input columns: [cluster_id, cluster_id, name];;

which says that the column names you are using is wrong, use one of the following methods

```
val nameDF  = clusterDF.join(df, clusterDF("cluster_id") === df("cluster_id"), "left")
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val nameDF  = clusterDF.as("table1").join(df.as("table2"), col("table1.cluster_id") === col("table2.cluster_id"), "left")
```

or

```
import spark.implicits._
val nameDF  = clusterDF.as("table1").join(df.as("table2"), $"table1.cluster_id" === $"table2.cluster_id"), "left")
```

or with newer versions

```
val nameDF  = clusterDF.join(df, clusterDF('cluster_id) === df('cluster_id), "left")
```